# prevent 2 in 1 laptop from disabling keyboard when folded

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, laptop, hardware, acer

I have an external monitor I use with my laptop and want to use just the keyboard section of my laptop by folding it but when i fold it it turns off the keyboard. How do I fix that? I don't even use tablet mode so I would be fine with disabling it altogether.

my model is Acer SP513-51-51pb

I've tried:

disabling iio sensor proxy via `sudo systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy --now`
trying to reenable it via `sudo systemctl enable iio-sensor-proxy --now` but I got the following output

```
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.
```

i tried finding the acpi as someone suggested but didn't know what to do after that

the output was

```
video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000001
 676AA15E-6A47-4D� 000000bc 00000000
video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000000
 676AA15E-6A47-4D� 000000bc 00000000
```

I tried `sudo acpi disable` for `0000008A 00000001`, `000000bc 00000000`, `0000008A 00000000`, and `000000bc 00000000` but just got a message about battery life. it said

```
Battery 0: Not charging, 100%
```

to be exact the bater level was at 95% at the time but that's kinda irrelevant

I tried using `xinput enable 13` and `xinput enable 5` after folding it neither worked.
here's the output for `xinput list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:3018 Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Naga Hex V2 Consumer Control  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Naga Hex V2                   id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam: HD WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Hex V2 Consumer Control  id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Hex V2                   id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Hex V2 System Control    id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Hex V2 Keyboard          id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`libinput list-devices` gives the following output.

```
Device:           Power Button
Kernel:           /dev/input/event2
Group:            1
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Video Bus
Kernel:           /dev/input/event8
Group:            2
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Lid Switch
Kernel:           /dev/input/event0
Group:            3
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     switch
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Sleep Button
Kernel:           /dev/input/event1
Group:            4
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Razer Razer Naga Hex V2
Kernel:           /dev/input/event16
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Razer Razer Naga Hex V2 Keyboard
Kernel:           /dev/input/event17
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Razer Razer Naga Hex V2 Consumer Control
Kernel:           /dev/input/event18
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Razer Razer Naga Hex V2 System Control
Kernel:           /dev/input/event19
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Razer Razer Naga Hex V2
Kernel:           /dev/input/event21
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System
Kernel:           /dev/input/event4
Group:            6
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             274x154mm
Capabilities:     touch 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      identity matrix
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           HD WebCam: HD WebCam
Kernel:           /dev/input/event7
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           ELAN0501:00 04F3:3018 Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             100x61mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   none
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Intel Virtual Button driver
Kernel:           /dev/input/event5
Group:            9
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard switch
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
Kernel:           /dev/input/event10
Group:            10
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
Kernel:           /dev/input/event11
Group:            10
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
Kernel:           /dev/input/event12
Group:            10
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
Kernel:           /dev/input/event13
Group:            10
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
Kernel:           /dev/input/event14
Group:            10
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10
Kernel:           /dev/input/event15
Group:            10
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Kernel:           /dev/input/event3
Group:            11
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Acer WMI hotkeys
Kernel:           /dev/input/event9
Group:            12
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a
```

inparticular

```
Device:           Lid Switch
Kernel:           /dev/input/event0
Group:            3
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     switch
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a
```

seems like it would work but I couldn't figure out how to disable a libinput device

`libinput disable 3` returns

```
libinput: disable is not a libinput command or not installed. See 'libinput --help'
```

and `libinput --help` returns

```
Usage: libinput [--help|--version] <command> [<args>]

Global options:
  --help ...... show this help and exit
  --version ... show version information and exit

Commands:
  list-devices
    List all devices with their default configuration options

  debug-events
    Print events to stdout

  debug-gui
    Display a simple GUI to visualize libinput's events.

  measure <feature>
    Measure various device properties. See the man page for more info
```

none of the remaining 3 seem to be what I need.

I also tried gnome tweaks and disabled "suspend when lid is closed" in hopes that it would turn off the lid sensor all-together but that didn't work as I thought.

using `gnome-teaks` gave me this weird output too

```
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
WARNING : Shell not running
NoneType: None
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 216, in __init__
    raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available
```

I get that kinda of stuff all the time when I try to launch stuff through the terminal. For example.

```
sudo gedit /home/ys/Desktop/acpi.txt

(gedit:28387): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:33:21.577: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(gedit:28387): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:33:21.618: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(gedit:28387): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:33:21.619: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(gedit:28387): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:33:21.619: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(gedit:28387): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:33:21.619: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(gedit:28387): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:33:21.619: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(gedit:28387): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:33:21.619: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
```

but that's not really the problem at hand and the stuff sticks anyways.

so tl:dr (kinda) - I'm trying to prevent my laptop from entering tablet mode when I fold it so far I've tried iio sensor proxy, xinput, gnome tweaks, acpi, and libinput but had no idea how to use the last two.

Comment: Actually, use `xinput disable 3` instead of `libinput disable 3` (I don't know from where you got this command) . The Issue could be at BIOS/ACPI level. Have you tried looking at BIOS setup if there any custom features there.